# does the zero vector lie in the span of every sequence of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

is the zero vector in the span of every sequence of vectors? For example, would (0,0,0) lie in the span of (1,0,1),(2,3,0)?

Comment: The 0 vector is in every vector space, and a verification of "is this abstract space a vector space?" should include checking the 0 vector.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Depending on your definition of span, it is either the smallest subspace containing a set of vectors (and hence $0$ belongs to it because $0$ is a member of any subspace) or it is the set of all linear combinations in which case the empty sum convention kicks in. Even $\mathrm{span}\,\varnothing = \{0\}$ contains $0$ (and nothing else).

Comment: thank you! that's a very helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes

$0\times (1,0,1)+0\times (2,3,0)=(0,0,0) $

so $(0,0,0) \in span\{(2,3,0);(1,0,1)\}$